# Apache 2.4 localhost virtualhost not working

Tags: dns, apache-http-server, localhost

I’ve been trying to figure this out for days. I just want to be able to reference my local test environment with: `placeholder.test`

I have the following in my `httpd-vhosts.conf`:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  DocumentRoot /root
  ServerName localhost

<Directory /root/site>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$ index.php?action=$1
</Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

This is working. I have the rewriterule in there because the site is designed to work that way but I cant get the virtual host for `placeholder.test` working.

My entry for `placeholder.test` looks like this:

```
<VirtualHost placeholdercms.test:80> 
    DocumentRoot /root/site
    ServerName placeholder.test
    ServerAlias www.placeholder.test

<Directory /root/site>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$ index.php?action=$1
</Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

In addition I have edited my hosts file to include the following:

```
127.0.01 localhost
::1 localhost
127.0.0.1 placeholder.test
127.0.0.1 www.placeholder.test
```

No matter what I do I get:

> The host name resolution (DNS lookup) for this host name
>   (`placeholder.test`) has failed.

I think I’m missing some basic but vital piece of information. Any help would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be nothing in the [apache 2.4 VirtualHost examples doc](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/vhosts/examples.html) that makes me think there's support for FQDNs in the `VirtualHost` directive.

I guess that the `VirtualHost` parameter is the attribute where the apache2 instance should be listening to. Most people set it to `*` so it listens to all interfaces. You can even make it specific for a different interface if you want, but there seems not to be an example with a FQDN. So I'd change it to:

```
<VirtualHost *:80> 
   ...
</VirtualHost>
```

Additionally, you'll have to define the same entry for **your local** `/etc/hosts` file with the IP address of the machine that should be running your apache2 instance.

Answer (score 0):

> I think I’m missing some basic but vital piece of information.

Yes, you are. Look at the virtual host configuration you have provided:

```
<VirtualHost placeholdercms.test:80> 
    DocumentRoot /root/site
    ServerName placeholder.test
    ServerAlias www.placeholder.test

<Directory /root/site>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$ index.php?action=$1
</Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

Now look at the very first line of that config:

```
<VirtualHost placeholdercms.test:80>
```

That `placeholdercms.test` is what is choking the setup. Just change it to:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
```

The `*` and `ServerName`/`ServerAlias` combo is what works for virtual host setups like this.